# Find the sub-sequential limits of a recursive sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recursion

Given $a_1 \in \mathbb R$ . Consider the   sequence  $\{a_n\}$, which is recursively  defined by$$
a_{n+1} =\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}  
\dfrac {a_n}{2} &  \text{if $n$ is even,}\\  \dfrac {1 + a_n }{2} &  \text{if $n$ is odd}.\end{array}
\right.
$$

Find the sub-sequential limit of this sequence.

I think  for  odd  $n$  the  limit  point will be   $l= \frac{1+l}{2}$ now  $2l = 1+l$  , here $ l = 1$

I don't  know the  limit point for0 even  $n$.

Please help me.

Comment: It does seem like, for any integer staring point, the sequence will always drop down to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that
$$
a_{n+2}=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
\dfrac{a_n+1}{4} &\text{if $n$ odd}  \\
\dfrac{a_n+2}{4} &\text{if $n$ even} 
\end{array}
\right.
$$
It can be readily shown that each of the subsequence, $\{a_{2n}\}$ and $\{a_{2n-1}\}$ is monotonic and bounded, and hence convergent.

Hence
$$
a_{2n}\to \frac{2}{3}, \quad\text{while}\quad a_{2n-1}\to \frac{1}{3}.
$$

Comment: S..but i did n 't understand how  u got this..$$
a_{n+2}=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
\dfrac{a_n+1}{4} &\text{if $n$ odd}  \\
\dfrac{a_n+2}{4} &\text{if $n$ even} 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then $a_{n+1}=\frac{1+a_n}{2}$, but then $n-1$ is even and hence $a_{n+1}=\frac{1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{2}}{2}=\frac{2+a_{n-1}}{4}$.

Comment: thanks  a lot @Yiorgos,,,,,i got it